# How to detect if the FreeBSD disklabel is on the first sector of the disk?

Tags: partition, mbr

I have attached a FreeBSD disk to my Linux machine. How to detect if the *disklabel*(aka *bsdlabel*) is on the first sector of the disk or the PC MBR is on the first sector of the disk and *disklabel* is nested inside the primary partition of the PC MBR? *fdisk* tells following:

```
T42 ~ # fdisk -lu /dev/sdc
This disk has both DOS and BSD magic.
Give the 'b' command to go to BSD mode.

Disk /dev/sdc: 256 MB, 256901120 bytes
8 heads, 32 sectors/track, 1960 cylinders, total 501760 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          32      187903       93936   a5  FreeBSD
T42 ~ #
```

First 512 bytes of the disk can be seen below:

```
T42 ~ # dd if=/dev/sdc count=1 | hexdump -C
00000000  fc 31 c0 8e c0 8e d8 8e  d0 bc 00 7c be 1a 7c bf  |.1.........|..|.|
00000010  1a 06 b9 e6 01 f3 a4 e9  00 8a 31 f6 bb be 07 b1  |..........1.....|
00000020  04 38 2f 74 08 7f 78 85  f6 75 74 89 de 80 c3 10  |.8/t..x..ut.....|
00000030  e2 ef 85 f6 75 02 cd 18  80 fa 80 72 0b 8a 36 75  |....u......r..6u|
00000040  04 80 c6 80 38 f2 72 02  8a 14 89 e7 8a 74 01 8b  |....8.r......t..|
00000050  4c 02 bb 00 7c 80 fe ff  75 32 83 f9 ff 75 2d 51  |L...|...u2...u-Q|
00000060  53 bb aa 55 b4 41 cd 13  72 20 81 fb 55 aa 75 1a  |S..U.A..r ..U.u.|
00000070  f6 c1 01 74 15 5b 66 6a  00 66 ff 74 08 06 53 6a  |...t.[fj.f.t..Sj|
00000080  01 6a 10 89 e6 b8 00 42  eb 05 5b 59 b8 01 02 cd  |.j.....B..[Y....|
00000090  13 89 fc 72 0f 81 bf fe  01 55 aa 75 0c ff e3 be  |...r.....U.u....|
000000a0  bc 06 eb 11 be d4 06 eb  0c be f3 06 eb 07 bb 07  |................|
000000b0  00 b4 0e cd 10 ac 84 c0  75 f4 eb fe 49 6e 76 61  |........u...Inva|
000000c0  6c 69 64 20 70 61 72 74  69 74 69 6f 6e 20 74 61  |lid partition ta|
000000d0  62 6c 65 00 45 72 72 6f  72 20 6c 6f 61 64 69 6e  |ble.Error loadin|
000000e0  67 20 6f 70 65 72 61 74  69 6e 67 20 73 79 73 74  |g operating syst|
000000f0  65 6d 00 4d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 70 65 72 61  |em.Missing opera|
00000100  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 00 00 00 00 00  |ting system.....|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 55 aa 80 01  |............U...|
000001c0  01 00 a5 07 a0 dd 20 00  00 00 e0 dd 02 00 00 00  |...... .........|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.0160705 s, 31.9 kB/s
00000200
T42 ~ #
```

Comment: Good question, good research. It isn't a complete answer but you may find [MBR: Sector layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Sector_layout) and [Case Study FreeBSD disk labels](http://tutorialsto.com/os/freebsd/case-study-freebsd-disk-labels.html) to be worth a read. I cannot really vouch for their accuracy, though. Looking at the fdisk code would also be a good place to start, to see under what exact conditions it prints that particular message.

Comment: Not sure about this: does `file -s /dev/sdc /dev/sdc1` show the information you want?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit overkill for you, but I have succesfully used [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), to get information about the boot sector and other boot related files (for Linux + Windows set ups).

From looking at the script I see it does test for GUIDs etc. specific FreeBSD, so it probably gives you the information that you need (including a lot of extra stuff, so there might be more direct ways of finding an answer to your question).